# Python fails to compile on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, python-3.x, compiler-errors, raspberry-pi

I am trying to compile Python 3.6 on Raspberry Pi Jessie following the instructions [here](https://tutorials.technology/tutorials/67-Installing-python-36-on-raspberrypi.html) and I am getting the following error:

> running build_scripts
> creating build/scripts-3.6
> copying and adjusting /home/pi/Downloads/Python-3.6.12/Tools/scripts/pydoc3 -> build/scripts-3.6
> copying and adjusting /home/pi/Downloads/Python-3.6.12/Tools/scripts/idle3 -> build/scripts-3.6
> copying and adjusting /home/pi/Downloads/Python-3.6.12/Tools/scripts/2to3 -> build/scripts-3.6
> copying and adjusting /home/pi/Downloads/Python-3.6.12/Tools/scripts/pyvenv -> build/scripts-3.6
> changing mode of build/scripts-3.6/pydoc3 from 644 to 755
> changing mode of build/scripts-3.6/idle3 from 644 to 755
> changing mode of build/scripts-3.6/2to3 from 644 to 755
> changing mode of build/scripts-3.6/pyvenv from 644 to 755
> renaming build/scripts-3.6/pydoc3 to build/scripts-3.6/pydoc3.6
> renaming build/scripts-3.6/idle3 to build/scripts-3.6/idle3.6
> renaming build/scripts-3.6/2to3 to build/scripts-3.6/2to3-3.6
> renaming build/scripts-3.6/pyvenv to build/scripts-3.6/pyvenv-3.6
> Segmentation fault
> Makefile:603: recipe for target 'sharedmods' failed
> make[2]: *** [sharedmods] Error 139
> make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Downloads/Python-3.6.12'
> Makefile:496: recipe for target 'build_all_generate_profile' failed
> make[1]: *** [build_all_generate_profile] Error 2
> make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Downloads/Python-3.6.12'
> Makefile:477: recipe for target 'profile-opt' failed
> make: *** [profile-opt] Error 2

I am getting the same errors when trying to compile any 3.6.x or 3.8.x Python version.

Any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Does `sudo apt install python3` fail? Why are you trying to build from source while there are binaries available?

Comment: python should be pre installed on rasberry pi to test if it is installed type `python3` in the terminal

Comment: My raspberry is old ( Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie) ) and the packages python3.6 and python3.8 are not provided in the official repos so I am trying to compile it from source.

Comment: I fixed my answer and it should work

Answer (score 0):

To build python from source you need the development packages needed to install python.

This is how to install them:

`$ sudo apt update`

`$ sudo apt install build-essential zlib1g-dev \ libncurses5-dev libgdbm-dev libnss3-dev \ libssl-dev libreadline-dev libffi-dev curl`

Then follow the rest of the instructions given to you.

Comment: My raspberry is old ( Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie) ) and the packages python3.6 and python3.8 are not provided in the official repos so I am trying to compile it from source.

Answer (score 0):

When you trying to compile Python on Debian 8 you have to follow instructions exactly. For some reason if you running 'make -j 2' you would get this errors but while you running just 'make' it compiling as intended